# Firebase Auth - list of users by Custom Claims

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We're using Custom Claims in Firebase Auth to manage access in Firebase and allow custom UI experience.

We're now working on the User Admin part and we can't find a way to retrieve users by the custom claims.

For example, a user belongs to an organisation and have different access level - admin or user.
We need to allow the organisation's admin to see all their organisation's users.

We'd like to avoid using a separate database to manage organisation users to not double up the data.

Is it possible?
Can we retrieve all Auth users while filtering them by specific Custom Claim?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this? Did you save that information in your database and kept it all in sync with your user's customClaims ? Like, every time you set `admin: true` to one of your users, you would go and save his `userId` under an `admin` node/collection in your database? Something like that? Or did you think of something better? Thanks.

Comment: For now, we just load the entire users' list and filter it by the required claims. But as the list will grow, we'll probably add a doubling DB table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no built-in API to get a list of all users that have a specific claim.

There **is** an API to get a [list of all users in the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). So you could use that and then filter the users that have the claim you're looking for.

But performance of this will not be spectacular. So if listing all users with a specific claim is a common use-case for your app, you'll want to reconsider your concern about using an additional place to store the data. Duplicating data to achieve (well performing) use-cases is quite common in NoSQL.

Comment: Is there a way to inspect (using the Firebase console) the claims that have been set for a specific user?

Comment: You can do it with a function.  const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
          if (user.customClaims) {
            console.log(user.customClaims)
          } @cbdeveloper

Comment: is this still true?

Comment: Yes. If there was a new API that allows getting only users with a specific claim, it'd be mentioned in the documentation I linked in my answer.

Comment: This solution performs well, and might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255525/12763464