# How to get users from Firebase auth based on custom claims?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm beginning to use custom claims in my Firebase project to implement a role-based authorization system to my app.

I'll have a firebase-admin script which is going to set `{admin: true}` for a specific user's `uid`. This will help me write better and clearer Firestore security rules.

`admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})`

So far, so good. My problem is that I'll also need a dashboard page to let me know which users are currently admins inside my app.

Basically I'll need a way to query/list users based on custom claims. Is there a way to do this?

[From this answer, I can see that it's not possible to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902483/firebase-auth-list-of-users-by-custom-claims)

But maybe, Is there at least a way to inspect (using Firebase Console) the `customUserClaims` that were set to a specific user?

My current solution would be to store that information (the admins `uid's`) inside an `admin-users` collection in my Firestore and keep that information up-to-date with the any admin `customClaims` that I set or revoke. Can you think of a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you just create a User node in the database then write a specific property like : "IsAdmin: true" ?

Comment: Because from what I understood that would make my Firestore security rules much more complex. See [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs). I would have to read from another place (like the one you suggested) in my database before allowing a read/write operation on some protected data.

Comment: @cbdev420 Actually the solution described in the SO Question/answer you mention in your Question and the proposal of Christophe does not change the way authorisation is implemented: it still uses the Custom Claims (and all their advantages) but, in parallel, the list of your users WITH theirs Claims is stored in the Firebase database.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Auth - list of users by Custom Claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902483/firebase-auth-list-of-users-by-custom-claims)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this use case recently, by duplicating the custom claims as "roles" array field into the according firestore '*users/{uid}/private-user/{data}*' documents. In my scenario I had to distinguish between two roles ("admin" and "superadmin"). The documents of the firestore '*users/*' collection are public, and the documents of the '*users/{uid}/private-user/*' collection are only accessible from the client side by the owning user and "superadmin" users, or via the firestore Admin SDK (server side) also only as "superadmin" user.

Additionally, I only wanted to allow "superadmin" users to add or remove "superadmin" or "admin" roles/claims; or to get a list of "superadmin" or "admin" users.

Data duplication is quite common in the NoSQL world, and is NOT considered as a bad practice.

### Here is my code (Node.js/TypeScript)

First, the firebase cloud function implementation (requires Admin SDK) to add a custom user claim/role.

Note, that the "superadmin" validation line

```
await validateUserClaim(functionName, context, "superadmin")
```

must be removed until at least one "superadmin" has been created that can be used later on to add or remove additional roles/claims to users!

```
const functionName = "add-admin-user"

export default async (
  payload: string,
  context: CallableContext,
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    validateAuthentication(functionName, context)
    validateEmailVerified(functionName, context)
    await validateUserClaim(functionName, context, "superadmin")
    const request = parseRequestPayload<AddAdminUserRoleRequest>(
      functionName,
      payload,
    )
    // Note, to remove a custom claim just use "{ [request.roleName]: null }"
    // as second input parameter.
    await admin
      .auth()
      .setCustomUserClaims(request.uid, { [request.roleName]: true })
    const userDoc = await db
      .collection(`users/${request.uid}/private-user`)
      .doc("data")
      .get()
    const roles = userDoc.data()?.roles ?? []
    if (roles.indexOf(request.roleName) === -1) {
      roles.push(request.roleName)
      db.collection(`users/${request.uid}/private-user`)
        .doc("data")
        .set({ roles }, { merge: true })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw logAndReturnHttpsError(
      "internal",
      `Firestore ${functionName} not executed. Failed to add 'admin' or ` +
      `'superadmin' claim to user. (${(<Error>e)?.message})`,
        `${functionName}/internal`,
      e,
     )
  }
}
```

Second, the firebase cloud function implementation (requires Admin SDK) that returns a list of "superadmin" or "admin" users.

```
const functionName = "get-admin-users"

export default async (
  payload: string,
  context: CallableContext,
): Promise<GetAdminUsersResponse> => {
  try {
    validateAuthentication(functionName, context)
    validateEmailVerified(functionName, context)
    await validateUserClaim(functionName, context, "superadmin")
    const request = parseRequestPayload<GetAdminUsersRequest>(
      functionName,
      payload,
    )
    const adminUserDocs = await db
      .collectionGroup("private-user")
      .where("roles", "array-contains", request.roleName)
      .get()

    const admins = adminUserDocs.docs.map((doc) => {
      return {
        uid: doc.data().uid,
        username: doc.data().username,
        email: doc.data().email,
        roleName: request.roleName,
      }
    })
    return { admins }
  } catch (e) {
    throw logAndReturnHttpsError(
      "internal",
      `Firestore ${functionName} not executed. Failed to query admin users. (${
        (<Error>e)?.message
      })`,
      `${functionName}/internal`,
      e,
    )
  }
}
```

And third, the validation helper functions (require the Admin SDK).

```
export type AdminRoles = "admin" | "superadmin"

export const validateAuthentication = (
  functionName: string,
  context: CallableContext,
): void => {
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth?.uid) {
    throw logAndReturnHttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      `Firestore ${functionName} not executed. User not authenticated.`,
      `${functionName}/unauthenticated`,
    )
  }
}

export const validateUserClaim = async (
  functionName: string,
  context: CallableContext,
  roleName: AdminRoles,
): Promise<void> => {
  if (context.auth?.uid) {
    const hasRole = await admin
      .auth()
      .getUser(context.auth?.uid)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        return !!userRecord.customClaims?.[roleName]
      })
    if (hasRole) {
      return
    }
  }
  throw logAndReturnHttpsError(
    "unauthenticated",
    `Firestore ${functionName} not executed. User not authenticated as ` +
      `'${roleName}'. `,
    `${functionName}/unauthenticated`,
  )
}

export const validateEmailVerified = async (
  functionName: string,
  context: CallableContext,
): Promise<void> => {
  if (context.auth?.uid) {
    const userRecord = await auth.getUser(context.auth?.uid)
    if (!userRecord.emailVerified) {
      throw logAndReturnHttpsError(
        "unauthenticated",
        `Firestore ${functionName} not executed. Email is not verified.`,
        `${functionName}/email-not-verified`,
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, custom claims can be added or removed only on the server side as the according "setCustomUserClaims" function belong to the firebase Admin SDK, whereas the "get-admin-users" function could be implemented also on the client side. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#node.js) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902483/firebase-auth-list-of-users-by-custom-claims) you will find more information about custom claims, including firestore rules for client side queries protected by a custom user claim/role.